# Programmatically enable option "Confirm before exiting Matlab"

Tags: matlab

I carefully set up a bunch of subwindows and tabs in the Variable Explorer.  The tabs were displaying data in deeply nested data structures, so it takes quite a bit of manual browsing.

Then I closed Matlab by accident.  Ouch.

To prevent this in the future, I found the [Confirm before exiting](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2007/05/29/oops-i-accidentally-closed-matlab) option.  I would like to set this programmatically so that it can be put into my startup.m file.  That way, no matter what computer I'm using, as long as I have my startup.m, I won't fall prey to the erroneously closing of Matlab.

Is it possible to enable this option using Matlab statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved using [Undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/changing-system-preferences-programmatically) features, so this behavior can change at any time without prior notice.

MATLAB saves the preferences in a file called `matlab.prf`, which is saved at the path

```
fullfile(prefdir,'matlab.prf')
```

The value of a variable can be read or written to using the Java commands

```
com.mathworks.services.Prefs.get<type>Pref(<pref-name>)
com.mathworks.services.Prefs.set<type>Pref(<pref-name>, newValue);
```

The "Confirm before exiting MATLAB" variable is a boolean called `MatlabExitConfirm`, so you can set it programmatically with

```
com.mathworks.services.Prefs.setBooleanPref('MatlabExitConfirm',1)
```

Comment: Thanks, hbaderts.  The statement works exactly as advertised in startup.m.  I don't even have to know java.

Answer (score 2):

The other option is as follows:

The fact is when MATLAB receives an `exit` command it first looks for a script `finish.m` and if it finds it the script would be executed before the program quits.

There are two sample scripts, provided by MATLAB in the `...\toolbox\local` path of MATLAB, for instance in my installation:

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\local
```

The files are called `finishdlg.m` and `finishsav.m`. The firs one includes a confirmation dialog-box and the second includes the process of saving the workspace.

So you should:

1. copy the 'finishdlg.m',
2. rename it to `finish.m` and then
3. paste in the current folder or the folders that MATLAB can **see**.

This way, when you `exit` MATLAB it first runs the script which includes a dialog box to confirm the exit command.

The code inside the `finishdlg.m` includes:

```
Yes = getString(message('MATLAB:finishdlg:Yes'));
No = getString(message('MATLAB:finishdlg:No'));
button = questdlg(getString(message('MATLAB:finishdlg:ReadyToQuit')), ...
                  getString(message('MATLAB:finishdlg:ExitingDialogTitle')),Yes,No,No);
switch button
  case Yes,
    disp(getString(message('MATLAB:finishdlg:ExitingMATLAB')));
      %Save variables to matlab.mat
      save 
  case No,
    quit cancel;
end
```

Of course you can modify it easily.

Comment: Thanks, NKN.  Your use of finish.m offers a lot of flexibility on close-out checks and activities.  At the moment, I'm only trying to activate the quit confirmation switch.  I appreciate your example code as reference for more sophisticated close-out actions.

Comment: @user36800 sure, no problem.